# Do you remember a TV play in the 1970s/80s about clones?

Tags: story-identification, tv, clones

I am trying to find out if anyone else remembers this:

- UK play on TV from late 1970s or early 1980s
- Featured 2 scientists coming home from work. They explain to their wives (classic sexist set up) that they have successfully cloned themselves. The only trouble is that the clones don’t last more than a few hours.
- Each man then vanishes with a ‘pop’! They were clones!
- The 2 men then dash into the house… ‘did the clones come here?’ They ask. These must be the REAL scientists, but no, they also pop.
- Two scientists then rush in… etc

It has bugged me for years and no-one else remembers it!

Comment: Was this a TV play or a comedy sketch?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Something made me think of a Two Ronnies comedy sketch (which would be in the right time period). A quick Google suggests that they did a sketch called "Send in the clones" but I can't find a full description (or video) to see if it matches.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll see if I can find out more about that, although I don’t recall the Ronnies being in it.

Answer (score 5):

[The Giftie.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1086852/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

> What would happen if you could clone yourself? Two ordinary friends decide to try this with a new machine at work. Thinking that this experiment has not worked, the friends go home dejected. But further events prevail and a serious dose of mistaken identity ensues. Can the impostors be caught?

1998. A bit later than you remember. And the plot description is a bit off. But close enough to  recognise.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!